# Accessing array of python Structure in C

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I've been searching around the web with no luck.  I have the following Python code:

```
class LED(Structure):
_fields_ = [
            ('color', c_char_p),
            ('id', c_uint32)
            ]

class LEDConfiguration(Structure):
_fields_ = [
            ('daemon_user', c_char_p),
            ('leds', POINTER(LED)),
            ('num_leds', c_uint32)
            ]
```

Here is a simplified example function that uses these structures and returns an LEDConfiguration.

```
def parseLedConfiguration(path, board):
lc = LEDConfiguration()
for config in configs:
    if( config.attributes['ID'].value.lstrip().rstrip() == board ):
        lc.daemon_user = c_char_p('some_name')
        leds = []
        #Imagine this in a loop
        ld = LED()
        ld.color = c_char_p('red')
        ld.id = int(0)
        leds.append(ld)
        #end imagined loop

        lc.num_leds = len(leds)
        lc.leds = (LED * len(leds))(*leds)

return lc
```

Now this the C code I am using (I've stripped out everything involved with setting up python/calling the "parseLedConfiguration" function/etc but I can add it in if it is helpful).

```
        /*Calling the python function "parseLedConfiguration"
          pValue is the returned "LEDConfiguration" python Structure*/

        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
        Py_DECREF(pArgs);

        if (pValue != NULL)
        {
            int i, num_leds;
            PyObject *obj = PyObject_GetAttr(pValue, PyString_FromString("daemon_user"));
            daemon_user = PyString_AsString(obj);
            Py_DECREF(obj);

            obj = PyObject_GetAttr(pValue, PyString_FromString("num_leds"));
            num_leds = PyInt_AsLong(obj);
            Py_DECREF(obj);

            obj = PyObject_GetAttr(pValue, PyString_FromString("leds"));
            PyObject_Print(obj, stdout, 0);
```

My problem is figuring out how to access what is returned to the final "obj".  The "PyObject_Print" on the "obj" shows this output:

```
<ConfigurationParser.LP_LED object at 0x7f678a06fcb0>
```

I want to get into a state where I can access that LP_LED object in the same way I'm accessing the above "LEDConfiguration" object.

**EDIT 1**

I guess another maybe more important question, is my python code correct?  Is that how I should be storing a list or array of "Structure" inside another "Structure" so it can be accessed from the Python C API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your EDIT 1 clarifies the underlying question, let me put that at top:

> guess another maybe more important question, is my python code correct? Is that how I should be storing a list or array of "Structure" inside another "Structure" so it can be accessed from the Python C API?

No, that's how you should be storing an array of `Structure` inside another `Structure` so it can be accessed from `non-Python-C-API` C code. If you want it to be accessed from the Python C API, just use a Python `list`.

In general, if you're writing code in both Python and C, only one side has to bend over backward to work with the other one. The point of using `ctypes` `Structure`s and `POINTER`s and the like in Python is to allow them to work *directly* in C, without having to go through the C API. Conversely, the point of using functions like `PyList_GetItem` is to allow you to use normal Python code, not `ctypes` Python code.

So, if you want to store a `list` inside a `Structure` to be accessed via the Python C API, just store a Python `list`—and you really don't need the `Structure` in the first place; use a normal Python class (possibly with `__slots__`). You can write this code without importing `ctypes` at all.

Conversely, if you want to store structures that can be used directly in C, you can do that with `ctypes`; then, in the C code, once you've gotten into `Structure` guts of the `PyObject *` you don't need the Python API anymore, because the structure is all C. This is usually the way you go when you have existing C code, and want to interface with it from Python, rather than when you're designing the C code from scratch, but there's no rule that says you can't use it the other way.

Meanwhile, if this is your first attempt at writing C and Python code that talk to each other, I'd suggest you use `Cython`. Then, once you're comfortable with that, if you want to learn `ctypes`, do a different project that uses Python with `ctypes` to talk to C code that knows nothing at all about Python. And then, a third project that uses the C API to talk to Python code that knows nothing about `ctypes` (like most C extension modules). Once you're familiar with all three, you'll be able to pick the right one for most projects in the future.

Now, to answer the specific problem:

First, when `PyList_GetItem` (or most other functions in the C API) returns NULL, this means there's an exception, so you should check the exception and log it. Trying to debug NULL return values in the C API without looking at the set exception is like trying to debug Python code without looking at the tracebacks.

Anyway, there are a few obvious reasons this function could fail: Maybe you're calling it with an out-of-bounds index, or maybe you're calling it on something that isn't a `list` at all.

In fact, the second one seems pretty obvious here. If printing out `obj` gives you this:

`<ConfigurationParser.LP_LED object at 0x7f678a06fcb0>`

Then you've got a (pointer to an) `LED` object, and `LED` objects aren't `list`s.

And if you look at your code, you don't seem to have a `list` of `LED` objects anywhere, at least not in the code you show us. You do have a `POINTER(LED)`, which could hold a C-array-decayed C array of `LED`s, but that's not the same thing as a Python `list` of them. It's just a C array, which you use C array syntax to dereference:

```
PyObject *led = ledarray[i];
```

Comment: Thanks abarnert.  I've made an edit which might be a more relevant first question.  Do you know how I would access that POINTER(LED) (AKA LP_LED) from C?  Seems like to access it as an array I'd need to end up with LP_LP_LED or something maybe?

Comment: `LP_LED` is basically a typedef for `LED *`. In other words, it's effectively a `PyObject **`. As with any C pointer, if it really is pointing at an array, you can just use it as an array; if it were a pointer to a pointer to an array, that wouldn't be much harder; just `(*ledarray)[i]`. How much experience do you have with C pointers and arrays?

Comment: This was exactly it.  Since I had a lot of the code written already and it seemed like the quickest path I chose to "bend over backwards" in C and change to using just plain classes in python and it worked perfectly :-).  Thanks a lot!